# cxf webservice in standalone spring application packaged as jar-with-dependencies using maven

Tags: maven, xsd, cxf

When running the packaged app like "java -jar my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar", I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 47 in
XML document from URL [jar:file:/.../cxf/javafirst/target/my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/application-context.xml]
is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 47; 
columnNumber: 61; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'sendServerVersion'
is not allowed to appear in element 'httpj:engine'.
```

This is due to an outdated http-jetty.xsd schema published at apache.org. And that is NOT my problem. My problem is that this does not happen in cases like:

```
maven jetty:run
```

or

```
maven exec:java
```

where the service runs directly against the unpacked binary directories and obviously finds the updated and correct http-jetty.xsd schema file.

I want to do basically one thing:

put the webservice into one jar including dependencies. That should also include all XML schema files because, obviously, it is not a good idea to make a web service dependent on outside resources.

What's the best way to do that using maven?

My possibly naive solution would be to copy the XML schema files manually into the resources directory and tell CXF to resolve them in the jar file. Therefore I have two more specific questions:

1.) Is it possible to let maven find the XML schema files and copy them into appropriate places?
2.) What's the recommended way to make CXF look up the schema files in the jar file?

3.) Is there any better, best-practice solution to that problem?

My maven configuration regarding the maven assembly plugin is the direct combination of the last two sections at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring has a very good mechanism to resolve the schema files that it requires - it typically does not download it from the web at all, instead using locally available files within jar files to get the schema and validate the xml, for eg. consider the context custom namespace schema in Spring, if you look at the META-INF/spring.schemas file in spring-context.jar file, you will see an entry along these lines:

`http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd`

basically what it is saying is to resolve the spring-context-3.1.xsd files from the classpath `org.springframework.context.config.spring-context-3.1.xsd` file

This applies for any third party library also, which in your case is http-jetty.xsd.

I think what I would recommend is to simply create a spring.schemas file in your jar file in META-INF/ folder, put an entry for the full path to the schema and replace it with a classpath version of http-jetty.xsd.